# None of the copy/move constructor/assignment is called while initializing

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Class A defines all copy/move constructor/assignment as follows:

```
struct A 
{
    std::string s;

    A() : s("test") { }
    A(const A& other) : s(other.s) { std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";}
    A(A&& other) : s(std::move(other.s)) { std::cout << "Move constructor\n";}
    A& operator= (const A& other) { std::cout << "Copy assignment\n"; s = other.s; return *this;}
    A& operator= (A&& other) { std::cout << "Move assignment\n"; s = std::move(other.s); return *this;}
};
```

And the followings are functions returning an object of type A:

```
A f(A a) { return a; }
A g() { return A(); }
```

The `main()` function is this:

```
int main()
{
    A a1 = f(A());          // Move-construct
    A a2 = std::move(a1);   // Move-construct
    A a3 (std::move(a2));   // Move-construct
    A a4 (a1);              // Copy-construct
    A a5 = a4;              // Copy-construct
    a5 = f(A());            // Move constructor + Move assignment
    a5 = a4;                // Copy assignment
    a5 = g();               // Move assignment
    A a6 = g();             // None!! Member-wise assignment (?)
}
```

Can anybody tell me, why on earth none of the constructors and assignment operators is called for `a6`? Which part of C++11's documentation describes this behavior?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: "member-wise assignment" is not an option here. You provided your own `operator=`. (And `T x = y;` is not assignment anyway).

Comment: The default constructor is being called and then the compiler is free to elide the copy. Great isn't it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called copy elision and is described in **C++ standard, section 12.8 pt 31.**

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
>   selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
>   object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
>   source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
>   different ways of referring to the same object (...)

The circumstances are described as well.  One of which being:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
>   would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified
>   type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the
>   temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

As g() returns a temporary anonymous object (not bound to a reference), is is constructed directly into the target a6.  In your example, the default constructor of g's return statement is used.

Answer (score 1):

With http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization in `A a6 = g();`, the code within `g` creates `a6` by calling one of the `A` constructors somewhere in the middle of the body of `g`.